# How to read a matrix from a text file in r

Tags: r

I am working on back propagation. I am writing the program in r. I have two separate programs. One for training the network and the other to run the trained network. The weights obtained from the training network are given as input to the trained network. The weight matrix is initialized as 3X12.

## first program (training the network)

## code to obtained vij

```
training <- function()
{
i <- 3
j <- 12
vij <- matrix(0,nrow = i,ncol= j)
vij <- 0.7 * vij
sink("G:/rvma/backpropgatn_610/trainedvij.txt",append=FALSE)
print(vij)
}
```

When I write this output matrix to a text file, the first 9 columns are stored as one set of data and next 3 columns are stored as another set of data.

## second program (trained network)

## reading vij from the first program

```
trained <- function()
{
i <- 3
j<- 12
vij <- matrix(0,nrow = i,ncol= j)
  vij <- as.matrix(read.table("G:/rvma/backpropgatn_610/trainedvij.txt",                                   header=FALSE))
  print(vij)
}
```

When I want to read the text file, it is giving an error:

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec
> = dec,  : line 1 did not have 10 elements

How can I read this 3X12 matrix?

Comment: you can read it from using file connection read. Then define the dimension of the matrix.

Comment: In order to provide much of an answer we need an example of what the data looks like. Are you using `r` to write the matrix in the first place? Is so please provide that code as well.